# How to modify this code to not ask for file. [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

This code could prove very useful to me, I just need it to have a set file instead of giving a choice.

'

```
<pre id="output"></pre> 
  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.getElementById('inputfile') 
        .addEventListener('change', function() { 
          
        var fr=new FileReader(); 
        fr.onload=function(){ 
            document.getElementById('output') 
                    .textContent=fr.result; 
        } 
          
        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
    }) 
</script> '
```

It would also help if it could read the file live, as it will change as the user is on the site.

Comment: So you basically want to read a file from the users hard disk, at the moment he visits your page? Without any interaction? Please take a moment to think about the security implications.

Comment: You cannot read random files from the file system. The user must either drop a file on an HTMLInputElement with a `type` attribute of `file` or select one using the file selector provided by that form control. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these are possible.

For security purposes, you can't just open up an arbitrary file someone has.  They have to choose it.

Additionally, the resulting file handle is immutable.  It does not change and will not update.

In the future, you'll have the [File System Access API](https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access), but it's not as if you can just open up anything you want.  The user still has to give permission and choose the level of access.

Comment: Let me make myself clear. I didnt mean a file from the user. I meant a file from the hosting server. Such as a text file.

Comment: @dfdgh You should post a new question.  What you want then is completely unrelated to all of the code in your current question.  The file element is for local files.  And usually, you would use the reader with local files as well.  Also, you're going to need something server-side to sync up new versions of the file, as polling isn't the best method in most cases.  (Unless, that is what you want to do... you should elaborate on your specific use case.)